# Postfix relay authentication for both server and client

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication

I built a postfix relay several years ago that relays through office365. This is limited to hosts on the VPN, but now want to provide a public IP and allow remote printers to relay through postfix for send to email.

My issue is a lack of understanding of how to add smtp authentication for the printers to use without messing up the authentication for office365. I think this is purely a perspective issue.

The new postifix installation is running in Docker using the config found here https://github.com/juanluisbaptiste/docker-postfix and works just like my old install.

Update :

Looks like I just need to figure out getting saslauthd to run in the container. Then it should auth against pam using a local account.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest solution, but it works for my needs.

Adding the following to the docker file

```
RUN echo -e "smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes\n\
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous\n\
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = \$myhostname\n\
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes\n\
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =\n\
   permit_sasl_authenticated,\n\
   permit_mynetworks,\n\
   check_relay_domains\n" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf

...

RUN adduser test; echo -e "test\ntest" | passwd test
```

Then adding the following under "#Start services" to the run.sh file created by the author of the project I referenced on github.

```
/usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam
```

I am now able to authenticate. Now to move on to TLS then deploy in AWS.